# When at a breakpoint in VS2013, typing is seriously slow

Tags: visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I have this problem that is really affecting my productivity.  I have a solution open with around 30 C++ projects and when I've hit a breakpoint and am paused in the debugger, I've noticed that typing in any other application is seriously slow.  As I'm debugging, I'm trying to take notes in Notepad (for example), and the characters that I type don't show up right away, but rather take between 1 and 3 seconds apiece to actually display.  Typing a simple sentence can take around 30 seconds to finally fully display in Notepad.  And until the final typed character is displayed, the mouse is completely unusable.  Has anyone noticed this too, or have any solutions for this?  I don't know why VS2013 being at a breakpoint would slow the keyboard input processing this severely in unrelated applications, but it's really getting aggravating.  Thanks in advance for any help!

- Steve

Comment: Currently it's using about 625Mb, but I've got a 16-core machine with 64GB of RAM, and am currently only using about 15GB total.  Memory and processing power shouldn't be a problem... this is an HP Z840 workstation.

Comment: I saw that first article, and just read the second you sent.  They both seem to concern VS performance itself though.  In my case, being at a breakpoint seems to affect my system-level performance - specifically with typing.  Super weird.  Thanks for the feedback though!

Comment: After some experimentation, I've found that the problem is not with VS2013, but rather the solution I have open.  If I create new projects and set breakpoints, there is no issue.  I think it has to do with all the threads that this one particular app is running, and all the locking mechanisms and timeouts and everything it's doing.  Messes me up.